# Error calling a method on GAITracker through NativeScript

Tags: nativescript

I'm trying to call the native GoogleAnalytics tracker in iOS using this code:

```
(googleAnalytics.getTracker() as any).setValueForKey(value, (global as any).GAIFields.customDimensionForIndex(key));
```

(`value` is a string here, and the output of `GAIFields.customDimensionForIndex(key)` is a string too)

But i’m getting this error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<GAITrackerImpl 0x2811e94a0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key &cd1.'
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

As per the [official docs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/reference/protocol_g_a_i_tracker-p.html#a286236dac84d8c6e8f4ec36d998d726d), it looks like only `setValue` method is supported.

Try,

```
(googleAnalytics.getTracker() as any).setValue((global as any).GAIFields.customDimensionForIndex(key), value);
```